# Table bucketing is not leveraged in a join spark Glue

Tags: apache-spark, aws-glue

I have a dimension table which is bucketed into 8000 buckets and key is (market_cd and account_id). While doing a join with a fact table key (market_cd and account_id), I am expecting the join shouldn't have shuffle (exchange) for the dimension. But that's not happening.
As show in the pic: The dimension is still going for shuffle.

Parameter addedd[image]
--conf spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=8000 --conf spark.sql.sources.bucketing.enabled=True